# Relationship between 2 custom posts in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I created 2 custom post types with "Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields" plugin in WP named `Company` and `Location`. Furthermore I created relationship field in `Location` post type called `parent_company_name`.

And now I'm trying to get posts by this relationship field.

I tried this code:

```
$pos = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => 1000,
        'post_type' => 'location',
        'meta_key' => 'parent_company_name',
        'meta_value' => $full_company_name
    )
);
```

however it returns an empty array.

I know that for relationship between post type and taxonomy I can make something like this:

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => 1000,
        'post_type' => 'compan_name',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'type_of_compan',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $company_slug,
            )
        )   
    )
);
```

But what can I do for 2 post types to get the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using plugin [Pods - Custom Content Types and Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/), which have it's own logic, creates table in the database for Relationship named [`{your-db-prefix_}podsrel`](https://pods.io/docs/database-reference/database-storage-relationship-fields/) and have a lot of [related options](https://pods.io/docs/learn/field-types/relationship/).

What you have is - 2 Custom Posts Types ( `Company` and `Location` ), which relates like: `Location`'s `parent_company_name` is some `Company`.

`parent_company_name` saved in the database ( in the `{your-db-prefix_}postmeta` table )  as `meta_key` for `Location` with `id` of some `Company` as `meta_value`:

```
 meta_id  |   post_id    |       meta_key      |   meta_value
----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------
 some_id  | some_post_id | parent_company_name | some_Company_id
```

And in the `{your-db-prefix_}podsrel` table with id's as relations:

[image]

2 ways from my side to achieve your goal:

1. You don't have `id` of your `Company` and only have it's name ( Title ):

   ```
   function ww_get_id_by_title($title, $post_type = 'company'){
       $post = get_page_by_title($title, OBJECT, $post_type);

       return (!empty($post)) ? $post->ID : false;
   }

   $pos = get_posts(
       array(
           'numberposts' => 1000,
           'post_type' => 'location',
           'meta_key' => 'parent_company_name',
           'meta_value' => ww_get_id_by_title($full_company_name)
       )
   );
   ```

   Here we create function `ww_get_id_by_title`, which returns the `id` of Company using it's name. We used [`get_page_by_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) function to return the id. After we just used `get_posts`.

   **Note**: this will work much slower, than, if we'll have the `id` of Company
2. You have the `id` of Company, which is `parent_company_name` for our `Location`:

   ```
   $company_id = 9;

   $pos = get_posts(
       array(
           'numberposts' => 1000,
           'post_type' => 'location',
           'meta_key' => 'parent_company_name',
           'meta_value' => $company_id
       )
   );
   ```

   Our `Company` id is 9 in this example.

Provided ways are just a basic. You can use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), work with [$wpdb](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) using SQL queries and etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, Samvel.
I simply used  $wpdb and it works.